# Laravel-Vite compile scss and js to seperate public/asset folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, vite, laravel-vite

So before, with laravel MIX, in the `webpack.mix.js` file, you can write

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/header.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/main.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/header.scss', 'public/css')
```

and it will be compiled to `public/asset` separately. Like the JS files will be compiled to `public/asset/js` and the sass files will be at `public/asset/css`. And when you put the files in the `head` of the `blaze.php` in your views you simply write

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/header.css') }}">

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/header.js') }}"></script>
```

How do I incorporate this with the now Laravel-Vite? Because when I run `npm run dev` the seperate files `scss` and `js` just gets compiled together in a single folder which is `public/build/assets/`. They are not being separated as to whether js file goes to js folder and scss file goes to css folder.

Here is what it looks like in my `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/sass/main.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: I'm going back to mix :)

Answer (score 0):

for use scss with Vite in laravel 9

step 1:- create app.scss file in resources/sass directory

> resources/sass/app.scss

```
// Variables
// @import 'variables';

/* The following line can be included in a src/App.scss */
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

step 2:- then made changes in `vite.config.js` file

> vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            // input: 'resources/js/app.jsx',
            input: [
                "resources/sass/app.scss", // scss file
                "resources/js/app.jsx"
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react(),
    ],
});
```

step 3:- made changes in Laravel Blade file. in my case, `resources/views/app.blade.php

> resources/views/app.blade.php

```
<head>
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    // @vite(['resources/scss/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.jsx'])
    @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.jsx', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.jsx"])
</head>
...
```

Done.

---

now as per your question I understand that you need to save build assets as custom path then [see official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#advanced-customization)

as per doc, we need to set `buildDirectory` key option in vite.config.js file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            // input: 'resources/js/app.jsx',
            input: [
                "resources/sass/app.scss", // scss file
                "resources/js/app.jsx"
            ],
            buildDirectory: 'bundle', // Customize the build directory...
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react(),
    ],
});
```

& laravel blade file will be as like below

```
<head>
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    {{Vite::useBuildDirectory('bundle')->withEntryPoints(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.jsx', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.jsx"]); }}
</head>
...
```

Note :- we need to install `npm add --save-dev sass` otherwise we will error about `Preprocessor dependency "sass" not found. Did you install it?`

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vite/laravel-vite-and-sass